# what is searchdisplaycontroller?

Tags: iphone, searchdisplaycontroller

When I give `IBOutlet` objects in my ViewController, I could not find out them in InterfaceBuilder to link to the object which are in the view.

After some time it comes automatically...(I have set correctly file owner) There is only one I am seeing that is **searchDisplayController**.

What is it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your exact problem but to answer 'what is searchdisplaycontroller' heres the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is used to handle search using a search bar. You have probably created an outlet for this in your controller. All the outlets generally do show up immediately after you declare them in you file's owner's header (.h). If you have created some outlet and still don't see it, try closing the xib and opening it again or quit interface builder and reopen.

EDIT: The UIViewController has a UISearchDisplayController as a property. You can read more in the [UIViewController's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW63). As your file's owner is a subclass of UIViewController searchDisplayController appears in the inspector.

Comment: Basically, its just there for every viewcontroller.